# Qubit configuration in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, transpile

Is it possible to make your custom qubit configuration in Qiskit? I know one can obtain the qubit configuration from different providers but I am curious whether one can somehow create their own configuration and then transpile their circuits on it- for example, say you want to see which configuration would be the most profitable for your circuit by minimizing the depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about creating a custom qubit connectivity. This is very easy to experiment with in Qiskit. The simplest way is to create a `CouplingMap` object which is the graph defining the connectivity between qubits. You canand use that as an argument to the `transpile()` function. For example, if you want to compile a circuit for a 5 qubit ring you would do something like:

```python
from qiskit.transpiler import CouplingMap
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit

coupling_map = CouplingMap.from_ring(5)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cx(0, 2)
qc.cx(0, 3)
qc.cx(0, 4)
qc.measure_all()

tqc = transpile(qc, coupling_map=coupling_map)
```

But, for more flexibility though the best thing to do is to create a custom backend object (or just the `Target` object, but once you've created the target it's 90% of `BackendV2`) that defines the exact instructions and use that as the compilation target. For example, building on the above example if you want to create a target custom ring backend that has random error rates and gate durations for the supported instructions you would do something like:

```python
import numpy as np
import rustworkx as rx

from qiskit.circuit.library import CZGate, RXGate, RYGate, RZGate
from qiskit.circuit import Delay, Measure, Parameter
from qiskit.providers import BackendV2, Options
from qiskit.transpiler.target import Target, InstructionProperties

class FakeRingBackend(BackendV2):
    """Fake ring backend with 5 qubits."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        graph = rx.generators.directed_cycle_graph(5)
        num_qubits = len(graph)
        rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=12345678942)
        rz_props = {}
        rx_props = {}
        ry_props = {}
        measure_props = {}
        delay_props = {}
        self._target = Target("Fake ring backend", num_qubits=num_qubits)
        for i in range(num_qubits):
            qarg = (i,)
            rz_props[qarg] = InstructionProperties(error=0.0, duration=0.0)
            rx_props[qarg] = InstructionProperties(
                error=rng.uniform(1e-6, 1e-4), duration=rng.uniform(1e-8, 9e-7)
            )
            ry_props[qarg] = InstructionProperties(
                error=rng.uniform(1e-6, 1e-4), duration=rng.uniform(1e-8, 9e-7)
            )
            measure_props[qarg] = InstructionProperties(
                error=rng.uniform(1e-3, 1e-1), duration=rng.uniform(1e-8, 9e-7)
            )
            delay_props[qarg] = None
        self._target.add_instruction(RXGate(Parameter("theta")), rx_props)
        self._target.add_instruction(RYGate(Parameter("theta")), ry_props)
        self._target.add_instruction(RZGate(Parameter("theta")), rz_props)
        self._target.add_instruction(Measure(), measure_props)
        self._target.add_instruction(Delay(Parameter("t")), delay_props)
        self._target.add_instruction(
            CZGate(),
            {
                edge: InstructionProperties(
                    error=rng.uniform(1e-5, 5e-3), duration=rng.uniform(1e-8, 9e-7)
                )
                for edge in graph.edge_list()
            },
        )

    @property
    def target(self):
        return self._target

    @property
    def max_circuits(self):
        return None

    @classmethod
    def _default_options(cls):
        return Options(shots=1024)

    def run(self, circuit, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError("Run not supported")

backend = FakeRingBackend()
tqc = transpile(qc, backend)
```

While this is a bit more code it lets you define different constraints and also specify which gates/instructions are available on which qubits (along with the associated properties of each instruction).